# How to limit logging of tomcat7-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm using the tomcat7-maven-plugin for integration testing my app.  Unfortunately, it spams WAY too much stuff to the console.  I'm getting debug level stuff from spring, and tons of other stuff.  What is the easiest way to limit the output to INFO level including spring and other dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a relevant logging configuration. I'm looking at a project that essentially depends on Log4j (it also uses SLF4J-Log4j so that dependencies that use SLF4J will still essentially use Log4j).

For this project I add a `log4j.xml` on the classpath. Maven, so that'd be in `src/main/resources` (which will be packaged into `WEB-INF/classes`).

My `log4j.xml` defines a bunch of `appender`s, but your real ask is about dialing back the logging. That is done using loggers and a root logger. Just some example snippets...:

```
<logger name="com.mydomain">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-MAIN" />
</root>
```

Comment: Since I'm using the maven-tomcat-plugin, how do I configure this?  The download and startup of tomcat is all happening inside one lifecycle step when I essentially run "mvn tomcat7:run-war-only".  How can I inject a new log file into tomcat in this way ("maybe a system property or something")?

Comment: I did try this and I can change the defaults.  I guess to be clear, I was hoping there was a way to configure the log level at runtime, not just at build time (of the war).

Comment: Look at `extraResources` (parameter of the plugin), although I've not seen it work, others claim it's the way to go (such as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21469068/1325216)).